# Perform joins in mongodb with three collections?

Tags: mongodb, join, mongoose, aggregation-framework, lookup

I am using $lookup for joining different collections in mongoDB. Now i am facing a problem here suppose i have 3 collections given below.

**user_movies**

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5834ecf7432d92675bde9d83"),
    "mobile_no": "7941750156"
    "movies" : ["dallas00", "titanic00", "green_mile00"]
}
```

**movies**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("4834eff7412d9267556d9d52"),
    "movie_name" : "Dallas Buyer's Club",
    "movie_id": "dallas00",
    "active": 0

}
```

**movie_comments**

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("1264eff7412d92675567h576"),
    "movie_id" : "dallas00",
    "comment": "what a great movie.",
    "time_posted": "1480516635131"
},
{
    "_id": ObjectId("1264eff7412d92675567h578"),
    "movie_id" : "dallas00",
    "comment": "awesome movie.",
    "time_posted": "1480516635141"
},
{
    "_id": ObjectId("1264eff7412d92675567h567"),
    "movie_id" : "titanic00",
    "comment": "titanic awesome movie.",
    "time_posted": "1480516635132"
},
{
    "_id": ObjectId("1264eff7412d92675567h579"),
    "movie_id" : "green_mile00",
    "comment": "Tom hanks did awesome movie.",
    "time_posted": "1480516635133"
}
```

User Movies is a collection where i am storing user liked movies, Movies is a collection where i am storing all details about the movie and movie_comments is the collection where i am storing comments associated to the movie.

Now i want to write a query where i am going to show users the list of their movies they have liked but all movies must have `"active" : 1`, and also the comments associated to that particular movie. Now i tried to use `$lookup` my code is given below.

```
db.user_movies.aggregate(
        {$match : {mobile_no : mobile_no}},
        { "$unwind": "$movies" },
        {$lookup: {from: "movies",localField: "movies",foreignField: "movie_id",as: "bmarks"}},
        {$unwind : "$bmarks"},
        {$match : {"bmarks.active": 1}},
        { $group : { _id : "$_id", movies : {$push : "$bmarks"}, movie_ids: {$push : "$bmarks.movie_id"}}},
        {$lookup: {from: "movie_comments", localField: "",foreignField: "movie_id",as: "comments"}},
        {$unwind : "$comments"},
        {$sort: {time_posted: -1}},
        {$group: {_id: '$_id', comments : {$push : "$comments"}}},
```

I am trying to write a single query for doing all this functionality and i am able to perform join on first two collections that is user_movies and movies but i am not able to perform lookup on third collection in the same query. What i want is to send output array of my **first lookup** which is **movie_ids** and send it to next lookup with **movie_comments**. So that i can have all comments associated with the movie i have in my `movie_ids` array.

Now can anyone please tell me why i am not getting any output, **can i use lookup like i am using it second time (which is using `localfield` as a `$group` field) or not than how can i perform this functionality in a one single query**.

**Update-** Now there is only one thing left, i want to get results in a sorted manner such that movies will be sorted like they appear in "user_movies" array(according to their position in array) and their corresponding comments will sorted according to 'timeposted' in decreasing order.

So for above documents i want my output to be like

```
{
     "movie_id": "dallas00"  // dallas00 is first because it appear first in "user_movies" movies array.
     "movie_name": "Dallas Buyer's Club",
     "comments": ["what a great movie.","awesome movie."]
},
{
     "movie_id": "titanic00"  // titanic00 is second because it appear second in "user_movies" movies array.
     "movie_name": "Titanic",
     "comments": ["titanic awesome movie."]
},
{
     "movie_id": "green_mile00"  // green_mile00 is third because it appear third in "user_movies" movies array.
     "movie_name": "Green mile",
     "comments": ["Tom hanks did awesome movie."]
},
```

Ok One Last thing if can get position of movies array string which is matched when i perform first lookup then i can sort according to weight which i will give(more weight to previous position and so on). So now what i will do is `{{$sort: { 'movie_weight': -1, 'time_posted': -1}}`. Now i will get my results sorted such that movies will be sorted according to their position in array `"user_movies"` array and comments will be sorted according to `"time_posted"` corresponding to their movies.

**Updated code**

```
{$match : {mobile_no : mobile_no}},
        {$unwind: { path: "$movies", includeArrayIndex: "movieposition"}},
        {$lookup: {from: "movies",localField: "movies",foreignField: "movie_id",as: "bmarks"}},
        {$unwind : "$bmarks"},
        {$match : {"bmarks.active": 1}},
        {$group : { "_id" : "$bmarks.movie_id", movie_names : {$push : "$bmarks.movie_name"}, movie_ids: {$push : "$bmarks.movie_id"}, movie_position: {$push : "$movieposition"}}},
        {$unwind : "$movie_ids"},
        {$unwind : "$movie_names"},
        {$lookup: {from: "movie_comments", localField: "movie_ids", foreignField: "movie_id", as: "comments"}},
        {$unwind : "$comments"},
        {$sort: { 'movie_position': -1, 'comments.time_posted': -1 }},
        {$group: {_id: { movie_id: '$comments.movie_id', movie_name: '$movie_names' }, cmnts_ids: {$push: '$comments._id'}}},
        {$project: {_id: 0, movie_id: '$_id.movie_id', movie_name: '$_id.movie_name', tot_cmnts: {"$size" : "$cmnts_ids"}, top_cmnts_ids: {$slice: ['$cmnts_ids', 0, 4]}}}},
        {$skip: page*page_size},
        {$limit: page_size}, */
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay, looks like you've bunch of problems. I'll try to sum them up.

Problem 1 : the aggregate code you've provided doesnt compile.

```
db.user_movies.aggregate(
{$match : {mobile_no : mobile_no}},
{$unwind: "$movies" },
{$lookup: {from: "movies",localField: "movies",foreignField: "movie_id",as: "bmarks"}},
{$unwind : "$bmarks"},
{$match : {"bmarks.active": 1}},
{$group : { _id : "$_id", movies : {$push : "$bmarks"}, movie_ids: {$push : "$bmarks.movie_id"}}},
{$lookup: {from: "movie_comments", localField: "",foreignField: "movie_id",as: "comments"}},
{$unwind : "$comments"},
{$sort: {time_posted: -1}},
{$group: {_id: '$_id', comments : {$push : "$comments"}}},
```

Fix:

```
db.user_movies.aggregate([
{$match : {mobile_no : mobile_no}},
{$unwind: "$movies" },
{$lookup: {from: "movies",localField: "movies",foreignField: "movie_id",as: "bmarks"}},
{$unwind : "$bmarks"},
{$match : {"bmarks.active": 1}},
{$group : { _id : "$_id", movies : {$push : "$bmarks"}, movie_ids: {$push : "$bmarks.movie_id"}}},
{$lookup: {from: "movie_comments", localField: "",foreignField: "movie_id",as: "comments"}},
{$unwind : "$comments"},
{$sort: {time_posted: -1}},
{$group: {_id: '$_id', comments : {$push : "$comments"}}}])
```

Now assume you're using the same data you have provided.

Problem 2 :  `{$match : {"bmarks.active": 1}}` doesnt match any entry.

Fix : `{$match : {"bmarks.active": 0}}`

Problem 3 : No look up field defined `{$lookup: {from: "movie_comments", localField: "",foreignField: "movie_id",as: "comments"}}`

Fix :  `{$lookup: {from: "movie_comments", localField: "movie_ids",foreignField: "movie_id",as: "comments"}}`

Problem 4 : No unwind stage for movie_ids for previous look up

Fix : `{$unwind : "$movie_ids"}`

Problem 5 : No time posted field `{$sort: {time_posted: -1}}`

Fix : include field before sorting

So, to put everything together you need aggregate to look like something below for extracting the comments for each movie.

```
db.user_movies.aggregate([
{$match : {mobile_no : mobile_no}},
{$unwind: "$movies"},
{$lookup: {from: "movies",localField: "movies",foreignField: "movie_id",as: "bmarks"}},
{$unwind : "$bmarks"},
{$match : {"bmarks.active": 0}},
{$group : { _id : "$_id", movies : {$push : "$bmarks"}, movie_ids: {$push : "$bmarks.movie_id"}}},
{$unwind : "$movie_ids"},
{$lookup: {from: "movie_comments", localField: "movie_ids",foreignField: "movie_id",as: "comments"}},
{$unwind : "$comments"},
{$group: {_id: '$_id', comments : {$push : "$comments"}}}])
```

Sample Output

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5834ecf7432d92675bde9d83"),
    "comments": [{
        "_id": ObjectId("583d96d7e35f6e9c53c9e894"),
        "movie_id": "dallas00",
        "comment": "what a great movie."
    }, {
        "_id": ObjectId("583d96d7e35f6e9c53c9e895"),
        "movie_id": "dallas00",
        "comment": "awesome movie."
    }]
}
```

Update:

```
db.user_movies.aggregate([
{$match : {mobile_no : mobile_no}},
{$unwind: {path: "$movies", includeArrayIndex: "moviePosition"}},
{$sort :  {moviePosition:1}},
{$lookup: {from: "movies",localField: "movies",foreignField: "movie_id",as: "bmarks"}},
{$unwind :"$bmarks"},
{$group : {_id : "$_id", movies : {$push : {movie_name:"$bmarks.movie_name", movie_id:"$bmarks.movie_id"} }}},
{$unwind : "$movies"},
{$lookup: {from: "movie_comments", localField: "movies.movie_id",foreignField: "movie_id",as: "comments"}},
{$unwind : "$comments"},
{$group:  {_id: "$movies.movie_id", movie_name: {$first:"$movies.movie_name"}, comments : {$push : {comment:"$comments.comment", time_posted:"$comments.time_posted"}}}},
{$sort :  {time_posted:-1}},
{$project:{_id:0, movie_id:"$_id", movie_name:1, comments: "$comments.comment"}}
]).pretty();
```

Comment: Actually it is not working as my movies position is also getting changed by sorting on "time_posted". i think we should write like this "{$sort: { 'moviePosition': -1, 'comments.time_posted': -1 }}". What do you think ??

Comment: really the position is being changed ? what example did you use ?

Comment: hey i found my answer i just did a trick as you told me to use moviesposition i didn't sort it earlier, i sorted it with time_posted like this "{$sort: { 'movieposition': -1, 'comments.time_posted': -1 }}" so now my docs are sorted first on movies wise and then inside comments will be sorted according to time_posted now just a one simple thing left

Comment: i also want size of "user_movies" array i thought about grouping bmarks with size liek this "{$group : {_id : "$_id", movies : {$push : {movie_name:"$bmarks.movie_name", movie_id:"$bmarks.movie_id", "movie_arr_size": {"$size" : "$movies"}} }}}," but as here every docs which i will get from groupby will contain now "movie_arr_size" element i want to have it returned only one time are you getting that.

Comment: I mean i don't want movie_arr_size to be present with every docs which is returned after group by stage that's why is there anything by which  i can pass a global variable which will be my "movie_size" to pass on to the next pipeline.

Comment: also as you have told me the answer i am going to accept it, this is just the last thing i want to ask ??

Comment: thats not how the aggregation pipeline works. The aggregation stages are chained and the only way to keep the input from the next stage is to include it as the output of previous stage. You can include the "$project": {
    "movie_arr_size": {
      "$size": "$movies"
    },
    "movies": 1
  }
} as the stage after match stage. You'll then need to include this count variable in your next stages.

Comment: One other thing your comment_posted field should be a type number not string.

Comment: When i wrote this "$project": { "movie_arr_size": { "$size": "$movies" }, "movies": 1 } }, I got error The argument to $size must be an Array, but was of type: String

Comment: it is a string but i am getting comments correctly sorted according to time ?? am i thinking in wrong direction ??

Comment: Not sure about the array error you are getting.  It won't sort  efficiently  b/c those are milliseconds and should be stored as numbers

Comment: ok also i am not able to get size of my movies can you please help me why is this happening ??

Comment: Can you add         {$project: { "movie_arr_size": { $size: "$movies" }, "movies": 1 } }, after match stage and try ?

Comment: Hey thanks alot man it is working, sorry i forgot to accept your answer. Just one thing i was wondering, without using group to group movies by movie_ids i am able to get my same results can you please tell me why is this happening. I think this is happening because as each element is passed through every stage not the whole documents(i mean one by one). So without even pushing movie_ids in movies.movie_ids all at once you can use $lookup on each movie_id to have a join with movies_comments collection. Please enlighten me if i am thinking it in wrong way.

Comment: Are you there @Veeram.

Comment: If I remember correctly it was already there in the initial answer you posted and I kept it that way. I don't want to misunderstand what you are saying above. Can you add the example to the post ? I'll take a look and let you know.

Comment: Can you please tell me one more thing pls, actually how can i return total number of $movies.movie_id return by above query ?? i am abe to fetch total comments by putting count: {$sum: 1}, inside last group by stage but how can i return total number of movies that are returned ?? Please tell me i have searched everywhere but there was nothing on this ??

Comment: Can you please  add a separate question if you don't mind ? It's easy to answer and someone else can help you too.

Comment: it was just a small part of it that's why can you please help me here ?? please ??

Comment: may be you can add the sum in the group before the last group and use first in the last group to retain the count.

Comment: Can you please see my question this one is also about aggregation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41090280/in-mongodb-know-index-of-array-element-matched-with-in-operator

Comment: are you there bro please help me out i have two queries first one difference between speed of aggregation vs simple mongodb query which i have explained briefly and also i posted the question you told me to post at different thread please have a relook maybe by seeing my post and solution given by the others may be you could help me ?? Eagerly waiting for your reply ??